# Make different maven modules work together as an atomic build

Tags: java, maven

It's possible this question has been answered elsewhere but I don't know exactly how to google on this one.

I'm in the mids of a ant to maven migration and I split up 1 ant build into 5 maven modules.

What I try to achieve is the following:

Only one thing should succeed:

- A, B1, C1, B2 and C2 build together.

"A" may succeed or not, that's not a strict requirement, but:

- B1, C1, B2 and C2 should fail if they are build separately.

("A, B1, C1, B2, C2" is an 'atom' -> it can't be splitted)

I want this to enforce that for instance, if C1 is build, it fails and the developer (we are a big team used to ant) doesn't think that B1 is build as well.

If a developer would adapt B1 and only B1 and try to test the whole (C1 (an ear for example)) (s)he would be surprised that his change isn't there (a lot of time can be wasted like that).

There is one parent (on the root) that works (no magic there).

I tried with the

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce-property</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <requireProperty>
                                <property>parent</property>
                                <message>==> This project can't be build separately!!! -> Please build either the root or one of the "...-build" maven projects...</message>
                                <regex>.*</regex>
                            </requireProperty>
                        </rules>
                        <fail>true</fail>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Plugin but it doesn't seem to resolve the

```
<properties>
    <parent>web</parent>
</properties>
```

property in the parent pom as genuine property...

How can I 'tell' the maven-enforcer-plugin to take a maven property as property or how to I get to the goal (atomic build 'clusters') in a different way?

Thanks for help/pointers/solutions/feedback,

Also, this is one approach, if there are other ways of achieving the same result: even better :)

S.

Edit: I edited the question a bit to elaborate on the 'atomic' part,

as requested by khmarbaise I created a [github repository](https://github.com/bamboomy/atomicExample) with the structure and some comments about what I try to achieve.

Edit2: I removed the multiple parents stuff...

Comment: There several things which I don't understand. First what do you understand under `behave automic`? You wrote you have migrated a single Ant build to several Maven builds? Do you mean different Maven modules ?  Furthermore I don't understand the relationship to maven-enforcer-plugin ...and your property..Can you create an example project on Github what represents the structure of you migration....

Comment: I adapted the question.

Comment: Ok first step very good having something concrete to talk about. What is the intention of two-ear-parent, one-ear-Build ? Why having different "parents" and what do you mean by "atomic" ?

Comment: Ok, @khmarbaise -> I dropped the multiple parents thing, but the atomic reaquirement still stands :-) I hope the explanation is clear?

Comment: Please make a explanation what you understand by "atomic" ...part unfortunately I don't understand what you mean? You can build from root in one go ? And what is the problem here?

Comment: That modules A, B1, C1, B2, C2 are an 'atom', they can't be splitted so: only the root build should be possible, building only B1 for instance should fail, where if B1 is build from the root it should succeed...

Comment: Ah...Apart from that I don't see the issue with that you can't control that cause Maven allows to build parts of the reactor via `mvn -pl ... clean package` ...